# How do you install a bower component from a subdirectory in a git repository?

Tags: github, polymer, bower

I recognize that this may go against convention:

I am trying to install a bower component whose bower.json does not reside at the top level of the repository, so something to the effect of:

```
bower install https://github.com/myrepo/my-components/tree/master/my-specific-component
```

However bower responds with the following:

```
bower not-cached    https://github.com/my-repo/my-components/tree/master/my-specific-component#*
bower resolve       https://github.com/my-repo/my-components/tree/master/my-specific-component#*
bower download      https://github.com/my-repo/my-components/tree/master/my-specific-component
bower EHTTP         Status code of 404
```

How can I install a component from a subdirectory of a repository like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your git repository is public then bower [installs](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/lib/core/resolvers/GitHubResolver.js#L56) from https://github.com/org/repo/archive/tag.tar.gz.
If your git repository is private bower perform a git clone of the given url.

Since there is no url in git that can be used with git clone to clone a subdirectory of a repository nor url for downloading a tar of a subdirectory, bower cannot currently support installing from a subdirectory of a repository.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do a bower install from a subfolder. I think the convention is that bower checks the root of git repository (depending on the commit you are asking) and then install component and dependency from there. 
If you have a look on core elements and paper elements hosted in git, you'll notice they are hosted in different repos

You might be able to use git submodule to include git inside another git repo so that you can reference the submodule when you want to install using bower (not tested though)

Answer (score 0):

I tried submodule, but couldn't get it to work.  It seems it won't work with submoudle according to the discussion at [Bower does not download git submodule (DojoX candidate plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901693/bower-does-not-download-git-submodule-dojox-candidate-plugin) unfortunately. Based on @sheenathejunglegirl's suggestion, I created a repo to demonstrate the working approach using archived files.  This will be useful when the public JS files you need have not been registered with bower repo or not hosted in public git repo with bower.json.

Just zip up the JS files with a simple bower.json, and then access it through github's raw URL. The example can be found at https://github.com/barryku/bower-repo-example. It can be used with either of the following,

```
git install https://github.com/barryku/bower-repo-example.git
git install https://raw.github.com/barryku/bower-repo-example/master/my-bower-lib.0.0.1.zip
```

You may need to adjust the github's raw file URL it it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

My subdirectory under the repository root is client/. I moved bower.json to repository root and also put .bowerrc in the root directory with contents:

```
{
   "directory" : "client/bower_components"
}
```

Maybe this is acceptable for you. At least the dependencies will be installed under your subdirectory, bower.json and .bowerrc have to reside at root level though.