# Bower install linked directory in GitHub

Tags: git, bower, javascriptmvc

This is best described with an example. I'm trying to install the following repository:

https://github.com/bitovi/funcunit/tree/jmvc

The following `bower.json` works fine:

```
"funcunit": "git://github.com/bitovi/funcunit.git#jmvc"
```

However, the repository includes a link to another repository (`syn`) on a particular commit. When I install the components, it gives me an empty `syn` directory without the needed components.

Is there any way to have Bower follow links to other repositories like this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901693/bower-does-not-download-git-submodule-dojox-candidate-plugin

Comment: Thanks, was afraid this might be the answer.